# jQuery wrapping all words starting with a dollar sign

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I am trying to wrap all words in a string that start with a dollar sign $.

Im using this code below but it doesn't seem to work:

```js
    var text = 'blah $blah blah';
    console.log(text.replace(/($\w+)/g, '<text>$1</text>'));
```

If I take the same code and change the dollar sign to a hashtag #, it works:

```js
    var text = 'blah #blah blah';
    console.log(text.replace(/(#\w+)/g, '<text>$1</text>'));
```

Why does it not work with a dollar sign?

Comment: Because `$` has special meaning in a reg ex, like `+` - escape the `$` `\$`

Answer (score 0):

In regular expressions $ means match the *end* of the string. You can escape it by putting a \ in front of it to treat it like the character $.

```js
var text = 'blah $blah blah';
    console.log(text.replace(/(\$\w+)/g, '<text>$1</text>'));
```

Comment: @freedomn-m Should that be end? :) - Thanks for pointing that out.